# How do I wait for multiple promises to resolve but also include a set minumum delay?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, settimeout

I am calling two APIs with two different functions and having a setTimeout for both, is it possible to handle their timeouts in such a way that they finish in 10s instead of 15s.

```
function delay(s){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,s));
}

async function getXml(){
    let ans;
    await delay(10000)
    const {data} = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SwayamShah97/a3619c5828ac8ed8085c4ae295a855d9/raw/e4e372552e042bd8bd9e8ab87da93eb030114f86/people.xml');
    xml2js.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        ans = result
        
    });
    return ans;
    }

async function getPeople(){
    await delay(5000)
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SwayamShah97/0f2cb53ddfae54eceea083d4aa8d0d65/raw/d7d89c672057cf7d33e10e558e001f33a10868b2/people.json');
    return data; // this will be the array of people objects
}
```

Is there a way to run this code only in 10s, so that both the APIs get called in 10s time period

Comment: remove `await delay(5000)`

Comment: Like you want to change the delays or use `Promise.all()` to wait for them in parallel?

Comment: Yea, want to wait for them in parallel, so the entire code should run in 10s instead of 15s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forcing either one or both axios.get() functions to complete *below* some time limit (other than failing on a timeout), isn't doable, since you don't control the transport.

One thing you can do is force one or more functions to complete *at or after* some time threshold, with something like this...

```
function padToTime(promise, interval) {
  // delay returns a promise that resolves after an interval
  const delay = interval => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
  // caller can provide a singular or an array of promises, avoiding the extra .all
  let promises = Array.isArray(promise) ? promise : [promise];
  return Promise.all([...promises, delay(interval)])
    .then(results => results.slice(0, -1));
}
```

**EDIT** good idea from @VLAZ to append an extra promise that forces minimal time (then slice its result off later).

The caller can say:

```
async function getXml(){
  // op function, no calls to "delay"
}

async function getPeople(){
  // op function, no calls to "delay"
}

// run these both together, have them take *no fewer than* 10s
padToTime([getXml(),getPeople()], 10000).then(results => {
  // we'll get here in no fewer than 10sec with the promise all results
})
```

Comment: Isn't `padToTime` just a `Promise.all([p, delay(interval)])`? If you really don't want to return that delay promise, then add `.then(([p]) => p)`

Comment: Yeah, I like it better, @VLAZ. I took a roundabout way of avoiding that superfluous  promise in the result.  Will edit.

Comment: `let promises = Array.isArray(promise) ? promise : [promise];` is OK but it might be worth just changing the signature: `function padToTime(interval, ...promises)` then there is no need for that line ;)